# graphics to graphics2D without casting

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

I am doing an online tutorial about drawing using Graphics.

I wanted to use Graphics2D instead because I wanted the float functionality. Since Graphics2D inherits Graphics, I assumed that merely swapping out all of the "Graphics" with "Graphics2D" would work. It does not.

I would like to avoid using casting. Any  help?

Comment: show us your code (edit your question and add it there. use 4 spaces or one TAB as indentation to format it as code). the soution is probably to cast it only once, as in `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;`, and then use g2d from then on.

Comment: Most of the methods within the API expect a Graphics object, changing the par ayers to Graphics2D in your sub classes simply makes a new method that won't be called by the base API. Since (I think 1.4), the subsystem guarantees that the instance of Graphics passed to these methods will be a Graphics2D instance, so it's safe to cast. The method signatures weren't changed, as Java likes to maintain backwards compatibility where possible